# How to remove chirp without removing another important system components?

Tags: apt, kali-linux

I decided to remove some unwanted packages, e.g.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge chirp
```

The according package is removed but also

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
chirp kali-linux-full python-libxslt1
```

IMHO the removal of `kali-linux-full` causes my Kali Linux to crash. Could anyone enlighten me why is this happening or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`apt-get` installs and removes all dependencies automatically. **The following is likely to break the future operation of `apt-get` and friends**.
If you don't want that then just use `dpkg`:

```
dpkg --purge --force-depends chirp
```

If it is really necessary to get rid of the contents of the package, you should consider making a `.deb` file with a higher version number than the chirp that is installed that doesn't contain the contents.

Comment: Forcing broken dependencies is a bad idea. APT does not cope well with broken dependencies.

Comment: @Gilles, yes, I was not able to `apt-get upgrade` afterwards.

Comment: @sitilge I assumed you new what you knew what the side-effects would be when you indicated that those packages were unwanted. Maybe you should elaborate on why those are unwanted, maybe uninstalling is not what is the solution for your **real** problem

Comment: @Anthon The reason for removal was just to get rid of the packages I will never use. AFAIK the situation is different in Ubuntu - one can remove packages freely, w/o referencing to/impacting the core packages and relations.

Comment: @Anthon, anyhow, this was the answer that solved it (taking Giles answer in count as well)

Comment: @sitilge I am still interested in the background, i.e. why you wanted to remove these packages, that might help others as well if they have the same problem. Did you need the disc space? (and of course there is the question if it is necessary that `kali-linux-full` depends on `chirp`)

Comment: @Anthon, yes, mainly it is because of the disk space. Also saving network resources when not upgrading to the latest versions. I suppose it the distro specific feature, solution would be this: http://docs.kali.org/downloading/live-build-a-custom-kali-iso

Comment: @sitilge I am not sure if you can solve the issue that way, unless thare are alternatives for `kali-linux-full` and `python-lib-xslt1` that do **not** pull all this stuff in. The disc space is somewhat moot on modern computers, but network upgrade bandwidth, that I had not thought about.